# Unable to call POST from Angular UI Give 405

Tags: angular, post, angular-httpclient

I know there are already like 100's of question but posting it as they are not solving my problem

So, I have a multichain network setup which is up and running. We have API's to access the network .The problem is i am able call POST request from the POSTMAN but when i call same from the Angular UI it just doesnot work.

Just to add i am well aware of how browser and POSTMAN handles POST request but unfortunately i am not able to get this to work.

I am well aware that when we call a 'POST' method the browser send the 'OPTIONS' request but i keep getting 405. I have checked the code but unable to find an answer. Below is my Angular code:-

```
 var surl = "URL";

        let headers = new HttpHeaders({
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
       });

  headers.append("apikey","<mykey>");

       let options = {
          headers: headers
       }

        this.httpClient.post(surl,'{"method": "listpermissions", "params": []}',options).subscribe(value => {
            console.log(value);
          });
```

I have also tried header like below but it doesn't work:-

```
   const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':'application/json',
      'apikey': '<apikey>'
    })
  };
```

And also like this:-

```
let oheaders: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
oheaders = oheaders.set('Content-Type','text/plain');
oheaders = oheaders.set('apikey','<apikey>');
```

Any help ..?

Just in case somebody wanted to to look at request and response headers.

[image]

Thanks in advance,
Vishesh.

Comment: Is there anything in the response body from the server?

Comment: Learn about cors. Fully. Postman is not a browser but a dev tool so a preflight request etc is not made. 405 is method not allowed ie server needs to allow posts not just get requests

Comment: @AndrewAllen I checked the CORS and yes server allows it.

Comment: @WillAlexander Unfortunately no there is nothing in response body

Comment: Can you post request and response headers?

Comment: @AndrewAllen Below is my request header                                            
 Provisional headers are shown
Access-Control-Request-Headers: apikey
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: <URL>
Referer: <URL>
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36

Comment: @AndrewAllen Below is response header .                                                                          'code'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: false
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Length,Date,X-Vcap-Request-Id,Strict-Transport-Security
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, CONNECT, OPTIONS, TRACE, PATCH
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Length, Date, X-Vcap-Request-Id, Strict-Transport-Security
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 29 May 2019 19:48:31 GMT

Comment: Could the server be responding 405 to the OPTIONS request? Or is it definitely to the POST request? Have you 100% definitely verified your URLs?

Comment: @WillAlexander Yes, the server is giving 405 for OPTIONS as when you do a POST browser sends an OPTIONS request first. If you check the response header which i have posted "Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, CONNECT, OPTIONS, TRACE, PATCH" server allows OPTIONS as well

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: false?

Comment: @AndrewAllen Yes that's what is coming in response header.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**

I missed the part where you mention multichain. As there is no way to bypass CORS, adding a proxy server in front of the multichain is probably the only solution (until they add CORS support) https://www.multichain.com/qa/9805/how-to-enable-cors-in-multichain

**Original answer**

You should read up about [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), but basically your browser is sending an `OPTIONS` preflight request to your API because your backend is on a different domain/port than your angular frontend app. So the browser is actually checking with the backend, using that `OPTIONS` request, whether it is allowed to do a `POST` request to the API.

It works using POSTMAN since only browsers implement CORS, but not rest clients like POSTMAN.

The problem is that your backend server does not allow `OPTIONS` requests and returns a 405 status code to say that this method is not allowed. You need to enable that method to implement CORS.

You can enable CORS directly in your **backend** application code (using nodejs, php, .net...) or directly at the web server level (nginx/apache/IIS)

When hit with an `OPTIONS` request, your backend should return a 200 http status code (not 405), and also the following headers

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://yoursite.com (or use * for debugging)
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS (and PUT/DELETE if needed)
Access-Control-Allow-HEADERS: apikey, content-type
```

There might be more headers that I can't think of for now, but you'll get a different error message if something is missing

Comment: I completely agree to your point I worked with several web development applications and know very well about CORS. I think everybody is missing an important point in the question which is . It a "MultiChain" network which i have hosted. If it would have been any other backend i am sure i would have done the handling of OPTIONS much before posting the question. The "MultiChain" is a blockchain network which you might be aware have it own API's which is not developed by us.

Comment: @Vishesh You are right I missed it. The only solution I could think of would be to use a proxy backend, as there is no way to bypass CORS from the browser. https://www.multichain.com/qa/9805/how-to-enable-cors-in-multichain

Answer (score -1):

You should enable Cors origin, by using this chrome extension Here's [a link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) or backend developers should add header in their code on service methods.

Comment: What if he's got many users? I don't think you can ask them all to install a plugin to make the website work for them

Comment: No am saying for development purpose only, however in backend side they add annotation for the cors origin issue then there is no problem in production.

Answer (score -1):

CORS Issue

**405** **“(Method Not Allowed)”** response that Foursquare API endpoint isn’t configured to handle OPTIONS requests. So the preflight fails and your browser never moves on to doing the POST request your code it trying to send.